# Точность вычислений побитовых операций

Tags: javascript

Почему результаты разные?

PHP:

```
10010057100 >> 12; // 2443861
```

JavaScript:

```
10010057100 >>  12; // 346709
10010057100 >>> 12; // 346709
```

Comment: Ваше число больше 2^32, PHP не умеет орудовать такими числами и каким-то образом его урезает. А в JS такие числа допустимы, может там вообще длинная арифметика есть из коробки.

Comment: Но судя по вычислению js ошибается. Не так?

Comment: как раз php делает все правильно. А js похоже вначале сделал `and 0xFFFFFFFF` и потом уже делает сдвиг.

Comment: Действительно, php: `(10010057100 & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 12;` результат `346709`. Я ничего не понял, ну и бог с ним. Главное знать как получить одинаковый результат...

Comment: @Mike, суть в том что битовые в js операции работают с 32 битами, то есть сначала число обрезается до 32 бит, а лишь затем производится операция

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[цитата с mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Битовые операции обращаются со своими операндами как с 32-х разрядными последовательностями нулей и единиц, а не как с десятичными, восьмеричными или шестнадцатиричными числами.

Таким образом все что выше - обрежется.

[И немного спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-signed-right-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression >> AdditiveExpression

1. Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression. - lref ссылка на результат вычисления ShiftExpression
2. Let lval be GetValue(lref). - получение значения вычисления
3. ReturnIfAbrupt(lval). - проверка значения
4. Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression. - rref ссылка на результат вычисления AdditiveExpression
5. Let rval be GetValue(rref). - получение значения вычисления
6. ReturnIfAbrupt(rval). - проверка значения
7. **Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).** - перевод значения левой части к Int32
8. ReturnIfAbrupt(lnum).
9. Let rnum be ToUint32(rval). - перевод значения правой части к Uint32
10. ReturnIfAbrupt(rnum).
11. Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, **compute `rnum & 0x1F`**. - shiftCount, значение на которое будет сдвинуто число, вычисляется наложением маски на `rnum`, отсекающей все кроме младших 5 бит
12. Return the result of performing a sign-extending right shift of lnum by shiftCount bits. The most significant bit is propagated. The result is a signed 32-bit integer. - возвращает результат знакового сдвига вправо числа lnum на shiftCount бит. Возвращаемое значение знаковое 32-х битное целое.

Comment: @Sergiks, а как? вроде и написано что именно битовые операции  на диапазоне инт и поэтому к нему приводятся

Comment: [Наибольшее целое в JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) = 2^53-1, до 32-битных они приводятся только для битовых операций. Поэтому первое предложение в ответе стоит переформулировать.

Comment: @Sergiks, написать до Int32?

Comment: @Sergiks, вообще убрал его, так как практически дублировало mdn

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось несколько неожиданно:
Исходное число 10010057100 - 1001010100101001010101100110001100 (34 бита).
PHP и в самом деле корректно посчитал: результат 1001010100101001010101 соответствует всем старшим битам.

Результат JS - 1010100101001010101 соответствует отбрасыванию трех (или двух) старших бит.

Что интересно, сложение на таких больших числах в JS работает корректно.
PS. Если у кого есть PHP не под виндой - было бы интересно посмотреть на результаты сложения для 10010057100

Comment: проверил php на убунте (15.04, x64) - результат такой же как и у автора вопроса

Comment: @KoVadim а со сложением как? Будет к этому числу нормально прибавлять?