# Побитовое ИЛИ, проблемка

Tags: javascript, php, битовые-операции

Переписываю некий код с яваскрипта на пхп

```
function level(k, d) {
    return (k << d) | (k >>> (32 - d))
}
```

Получилось

```
function level($k, $d) {
    return ($k << $d) | abs($k >> (32 - $d));
}
```

Но вот проблемка, на level(14,8) яваскрипт и пхп возвращают одинаково 3584. На более крупных бяка level(10000,30):

```
10737418240000 | 2500 //js 2500
10737418240000 | 2500 //php 10737418242500
```

Где сделал ошибку?

песочница http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aed1b6d153c7c21518c317664a0a1b4d24dd2070

Comment: javascript это не java

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Точность вычислений побитовых операций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490736/186999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что битовые операторы в javascript работают только с 32х битными числами.

Все операнды и результат в итоге приводятся в 32х битному числу.

Например в случае со [сдвигом влево](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-left-shift-operator) реальное число будет `10737418240000`, если перевести его в двоичный вид, получим следующее:

```
10011100010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Как можно заменить последние 32 символа 0, что дает при приведении к 32х битному числу - 0.

Таким образом `10000 << 30` == `0`

Далее идет побитовое ИЛИ c 2500, и так как в исходном числе все 0 - получаем 2500.

---

В php такого ограничения нет.

Comment: хорошо, у меня была идея насчет точности. Значит мне надо вручную перевести 10737418240000  в двоичное, потом отсечь лишние биты, перевести обратно в десятеричное и затем сравнивать? Привильная логика?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, это ты с какой стороны js или php?

Comment: переношу на пхп, код будет работать на пхп.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, если хочешь чтобы поведение в пхп было таким же как в js - то да, нужно все приведения делать самому, не обязательно переводить в двоичное и обратно, достаточно взять остаток по модулю 2^32

Comment: не совсем понял "остаток по модулю 2^32"

Comment: видимо 10737418240000% (2**32) ? блин, моя 32-битная винда и пыха ругаются))