# Побитовый сдвиг влево, проблемка

Tags: javascript, php, битовые-операции

Переписываю некий код с яваскрипта на пхп, должен работать идентично.

Eже разобрался с [побитовым ИЛИ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927638/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0), яваскрипт сравнивает числа в 32-битном представлении. Теперь проблемка с побитовым сдвигом влево.

```
js 30 << 30 возвращает -2147483648
php 30 << 30 возвращает 32212254720
```

Хорошо, первые 32 бита, `32212254720 % (2 ** 32)`, получим `2147483648`, почти похоже на результат js.

Пытаюсь воссоздать логику js, число 30 в двоичном представлении

```
11110
00000000000000000000000000011110
```

Сдвигаю влево на 30 бит, получаю

```
00000000000000000000000000011110000000000000000000000000000000
```

Оставляю 32 бита

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Конвертирую в десятичное

```
2147483648
```

Но откуда в js берется знак минус?

**PS**

Всем спасибо за помощь, написал 3 функции `| << >>>`, а потом нашел готовую библиотеку https://github.com/simaguo/javascript-bitwise-operators

Comment: В знаковых 32 битных числах старший бит означает как раз знак. А js воспринимает их именно как знаковые

Comment: @Mike не понял ничего

Comment: Старший бит обозначает знак числа. если он 1 - то число отрицательное, если 0 то положительное. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Побитовые операторы в JavaScript работают с 32-битными целыми числами в их двоичном представлении.

Число `30` в двоичной форме это `0b00000000000000000000000000011110` (`0b` - это просто префикс, говорящий о том, что данное за ним число записано в двоичной форме. Так вот,  в тридцати двух битном представлении крайняя левая цифра `0` (сразу после `0b` и тридцать вторая если считать справа!) - что соответствует знаку `+` числа идущего за префиксом).

Сдвигаем это число на `30` позиций влево `30 << 30` получаем в десятичном виде `-2147483648`, а двоичном  (32-х битном) `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`, где старшая цифра (после префикса `0b`) единица, что соответствует знаку минус.

Comment: ага, хорошо, тут более понятно, `0b` пишем как бы для себя указание системы счисления?

Comment: Для системы, иначе она не поймет что это двоичное число

Answer (score 3):

Из курса дискретной математики, помню:

Для записи чисел в памяти компьютера используется различная система двоичных кодов...
 Существует 3 вида:

1)Прямой
2)Обратный
3)Дополнительный
(Коды)

Ваш компьютер использует для записи чисел - дополнительный код. Это не обычный двоичный код, в нем если первый знак является 1, то это отрицателеное число(то есть числа начинающиеся со знака 1, отрицательные числа)

Кстати Вы встретились с очень полезной ошибкой, в плане ваших знаний) Теперь знаете больше, мой совет кроме изучения языков, рассмотрите как работает ваш компьютер (это не в коем случае не наставления, просто совет)))
 Удачи!

Comment: ок, спасибо.....

Answer (score 1):

Ты осуществляешь операции над целыми числами со знаком. Первый бит отвечает за знак.
В джаваскрипте операция `js 30 << 30` возвращает `10000000000000000000000000000000` - это число в обратном коде (тебе написали выше) соответствует `-2147483648` в десятичной.
В пхп у тебя 64-битное слово, поэтому ты получается двоичное число с нулем в первом бите `000000000000000000000000000011110000000000000000000000000000000` что соответствует `32212254720` в десятичной.

Чтбы перепроверить удобно использовать программисткий калькулятор виндовс.

Если ты хочешь выполнить такую операцию на джаваскрипте - тебе нужно 64-битное целое. Используй [node-int64](https://github.com/broofa/node-int64) или [goog.math.Long.html](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.math.Long.html) из [closure-library](https://github.com/google/closure-library)

Comment: необходимо эмулировать работу js скрипта, в общем решение уже нашел.